# Textbook questions on Code Review

Tags: discussion, site-policy, homework

I have answered to four Scheme-related code review requests on the site, which are for proposed solutions to exercises from a famous text book *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* (usually abbreviated SICP) which has been used at MIT for a long time in undergraduate education. I have also taught this book in my own university in the past.

Is it appropriate for users to post solutions to exercises from well-known textbooks on Code Review, and for other users to help to improve them?  I wonder if this is good citizenship as it makes the life of professors harder as this opens a new, easily accessible medium for getting canned, high-quality solutions from a centralized source.

Should Code Review ban solutions to text book exercises from being submitted?

Answer (score 10):

> My question is whether it is appropriate for users to post solutions to exercises from well-known text books on Code Review

It can be, if they are posted with the honest intent of having a *working solution* reviewed for subjective and aesthetic feedback -- and not getting free homework help.

> I wonder if this is good citizenship as it makes the life of professors harder as this opens a new, easily accessible medium for getting canned, high-quality solutions from a centralized source.

Certainly this would be a problem on the greater internet regardless of our site's stance on this issue?

Regardless, I think it is 100% fair to ask the poster to justify their intent and it *absolutely* must be a WORKING, SOLVED code sample to start with. Code Review is NOT for code that does not work.

Comment: Isn't the issue less the people who are asking the question, and more people who find the answers on the side and simply submit them as their own?

Comment: Winston, the issue is both those people and the teachers who make no effort to determine whether or not a student has simply found their solution online rather than doing it themselves.